# Syntax for a nested expression binding [SAPUI5]

Tags: nested, conditional-statements, sapui5

i would like to set the visibility based on the tests of two different conditions. it musst fullfill the tests bellow.

*Things that i want to test:*

1. name !== ''
2. **and** name is not null
   **AND**
3. nr === 13;
4. **or** nr === 14;

Syntax:

```
<Button visible="{= {${modelExample>name} !== '' &amp;&amp ${modelExample>name} !== null} &amp;&amp; {${modelExample>nr} === 13 || ${modelExample>nr} === 14 } ? true: false}"
```

**Issue:** It does give out an error.

**Question:** What would be the appropriate syntax for this conditionals. Is it even possible to test two different things ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The readability of expression binding is kinda ...
if your condition get's to complex go for a formatter.(IMO better readability)

---

## [Expression Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0)

**JSONModel**

```js
    this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({
                name: "",
                nr: 10
            }), "json");
```

**XML**

```xml
<Button text="test" visible="{= ${json>/name} &amp;&amp; (${json>/nr} === 13 || ${json>/nr} === 14) ? true : false}"/>
```

---

## [Formatter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de)

**formatter.js**

```js
        myCond: function (sName, iNumber) {
            if (sName && (iNumber === 13 || iNumber === 14)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**XML**

```xml
<Button text="test" visible="{ parts: ['json>/name', 'json>/nr'], formatter: '.formatter.myCond'}"/>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your contribution, a sequence else if chain is finde and did work out however. How do i summarize this expression in one go ? What will be the Syntax for that  ?

Comment: oh..my answer was wrong, i adjusted the answer

Comment: In your expression binding you can remove the ternary operator. This is like saying `if value equals true return true else return false`. This can be simplified to `return value`

Comment: Hey Marc, if i remove the ternary operator like this: `visible="{= ${json>/name} &amp;&amp; (${json>/nr} === 13 || ${json>/nr} === 14)}"`, ui5 takes the value of `json>/name` as returning value. So if name is "" the following error get's triggered: *Error: "" is of type string, expected boolean for property "visible"*